# show to sort coredata with date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I am haing a Simple Iphone based apllication.In that Application coredata is is used for storing data.

I have two fields.
    one Field is Mesage and other  field is date.I want to take the mesage which is sent within last 10 days.
I know to this code is used for that..but how to implement this?????

```
sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:sortByStringDate context:NULL]
```

how to write a query and how to implement this...Anybody help me to implement                              this.....Advance thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
// Calculate NSDate for 10 days ago
NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; // get current date
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
dateComponents.day = -10;
NSDate *tenDaysAgo = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:now options:0];
[dateComponents release];

// Create NSFetchRequest
NSFetchRequest *req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"MyEntity"];
req.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >= %@", tenDaysAgo];
// Optionally add a sort descriptor too

// Execute fetch request
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:req error:&error];
```

If this doesn't make sense to you then read about NSFetchRequests and Predicates in the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html).

Comment: What happens now is that you click the button to accept this answer then.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sort array by property `date` of objects in that array you can write such call:

```
sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES]]];
```

Comment: Create new fetch request template. When fetching objects : load it and set appropriate dates.